# Как в Shutter запустить произвольную программу после скриншота?

Tags: linux, screenshots

Как добавить в список свою программу/скрипт, который будет автоматически вызываться после того как сделан скриншот. В **Actions -> Open with** есть набор установленных программ, но как их расширить? Plugin не интересен, так как требует дополнительных действий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб приложение появилось в списке Shutter, нужно привязать его к MIME-Type. Как пример

Приложение у меня **/home/user/MyViewer**

Создаем ярлык на наше приложение

```
~/.local/share/applications/MyViewer.desktop
```

С таким содержимым

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyViewer
Exec=/home/user/MyViewer %U
MimeType=image/png
Icon=MyViewer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=
Comment=
```

Добавляем иконку для приложения в

```
~/.local/share/pixmaps/MyViewer.png
```

Обновляем базу приложений

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

Перезапускаем Shutter и радуемся жизни
Имя файла скриншота прилетит в качестве аргумента